# How to make only one DLL when publishing asp.net website instead of "App_Web...dll's?

Tags: asp.net, deployment, dll, assemblies, publishing

I have a ASP.NET Web application which has 2 projects (one for UI and one for Business layer).

Now when I publish this for deployment, it's giving me so many DLLS in bin folder which starts with prefix "App_Web...." in the name. How can I make it into only one DLL or 2 DLLS (one for UI and one for BL)? I work with Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that these are the result of pre-compilation.  If you turn that off, you should stop seeing these.

EDIT: A bit of research into how to do this suggests that you're likely using a Web Site project for your UI.  If this is the case, consider re-creating it as a Web Application, and I think you'll be set.